# Zero Electric Potential but non-zero Electric field?

Tags: electric-fields, potential, potential-energy

A point **P** at the exact half way of two opposite charge will have zero potential (assume potential is set zero at infinity) ,but the electric field will not be zero at point **P**. How to completely explain this? What is the different to $E=-\nabla\ V$ and why?

Comment: What is the conceptual difficulty you are having here? Electric field is the negative gradient of electric potential, and zero potential doesn't imply zero electric field. In fact potential is defined only up to an arbitrary constant, sometimes fixed by the convention that the potential be zero at infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A point P at the exact half way of two opposite charge will have zero
> potential (assume potential is set zero at infinity) ,but the electric
> field will not be zero at point P. How to completely explain this?

You are correct.

The diagram below shows the electric field lines between two charges of opposite polarity. Clearly the electric field midpoint between the charges is not zero.

And you are also correct that the electric potential is zero if zero potential is set at infinity, ***provided that*** the point at infinity lies in the plane into the page midpoint between the charges. That's because a plane midpoint between the equal and opposite charges represents an ***equipotential*** plane.

> What is the different to $E=-\nabla\ V$ and why?

Since the plane between the equal and opposite charge is an equipotential plane, the potential difference between all point on that plane is zero. Thus there is no voltage gradient between all points on the plane ($\nabla\ V=0$).

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To make things a bit more graphical, here is the potential around the two charges:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The black lines are equipotentials, i.e. lines of constant electrostatic potential. In particular, the straight equipotential in the middle runs through the centerpoint of the system all the way out to infinity, where the potential is zero (under the normal convention).

The electric field, $\mathbf E = -\nabla V$, is the gradient of this landscape, i.e. it points downhill and measures the slope of the landscape.

So, in those terms, your question can be rephrased as

> how is it possible for the centerpoint of the diagram to be at height zero but have a nonzero slope?

and in that form the answer should be much more geometrically intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You are right $$E=-\nabla\ V$$ and V really changes in the direction of the charges, so you have an electric field along the line between the to charges, but none perpendicular to it, so you can transport a charge along this perpendicular line without any E -fieldso without any work .